# how to fix Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

my xampp is giving this error

```
4:00:43 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
4:00:43 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:00:43 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:00:43 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:00:43 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:00:43 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
4:00:43 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

I tried to fix the error by changing the port, but it didn't work, then I tried to change the data folder to the old-data folder, and it was fixed, but then the same error occurred again, and after a few days, I even uninstalled xampp several times, and it was the last one again. I installed the version, but after a few days it gave the same error again

Comment: It sometimes won't help just reinstalling if you don't know the root cause of some deeper issue. Have you checked the error logs and the windows event viewer?

Answer (score 0):

I added this into the mysql Config INI as a comment block...

```
#==============================
#if failing to start the db, uncomment out #the following line:
 
skip-grant-tables
 
#save, close, re-start mysql. 
#run: REPAIR TABLE mysql.db EXTENDED
#stop mysql, comment the line again and #start mysql again.
#===============================
```

Comment: Comment block won't solve any thing because it's comment!

Comment: Read it again. I think the instructions are pretty clear. 1st line says to UNCOMMENT the following line. S/E has issues with putting "#" comments in text/code blocks.